# Content of a file in Zabbix email alert

Tags: zabbix

How can I configure zabbix to send me the content of a logfile in email alert? I have an alert that sends me an email when a new line is added in a logfile and I want to add the last line in the email.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you alert based on a trigger like `{host:log[/tmp/file.txt].strlen()} <> 0`, then you can use `{ITEM.VALUE}` macro to refer to the item value that triggered the alert. If there are several items in a trigger, use an indexed version of this macro like `{ITEM.VALUE2}` to refer to the second item in the trigger expression. The default notification message that comes with Zabbix includes these macros, so if you have not changed it, it should work out of the box.

Please see [Using macros in messages](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/notifications/action/operation/macros) section in the official documentation for more information.

Comment: My triger looks like this: `{Template:vfs.file.cksum[/var/log/file.log].diff(0)}>0` . I tried to add `{ITEM.VALUE}` at Description but I didn't receive anything. Can you give me a sollution for this?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit where did you try to add `{ITEM.VALUE}` to? Did you try to add it to the action's message or trigger's name? If so, did you include `{TRIGGER.NAME}` in the notification? What exactly does it mean that you did not receive anything? Does it mean that you did not receive a notification or `{ITEM.VALUE}` was left unexpanded or expanded to an empty value? Do you really wish to receive a checksum of the file in an email?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details. Actually when I added `{ITEM.VALUE}` at Triger Description I received in alert email the checksum of this file /var/log/file.log. I don't want to receive the checksum of the file in alert email, I what to receive the content of the file or last line of the file. Now I receive a lot of false positive alerts and I want to add the content of log file in email (better will be to add just last line).

Comment: If you just need the last log line for debugging purposes, you can add a reference to the item that monitors the log file lines in the notification message, like `{host:log[/tmp/file.txt].last()}`.

Comment: If you need the last log line in notifications permanently with a universal notification message, then the common practice is to add a condition that is always true to the trigger and that references the item you need, like so: `{Template:vfs.file.cksum[/var/log/file.log].diff(0)}>0 and {Template:log[/var/log/file.log].strlen(0)}>=0`. Then, use `{ITEM.VALUE1}` to refer to the value of the first item and `{ITEM.VALUE2}` to that of the second item.

Comment: Thanks for helping me:) I tried to set a new triger like this `{Template:vfs.file.cksum[/var/log/file.log].diff(0)}>0 and {Template:log[/var/log/file.log].strlen(0)}>=0` and another one like this `{Template:vfs.file.cksum[/var/log/file.log].diff(0)}>0 or {Template:log[/var/log/file.log].strlen(0)}>=0` and I don't receiveed any alert from this trigers but from the first triger `{Template:vfs.file.cksum[/var/log/file.log].diff(0)}>0` i received. I don't know what I missed.

Comment: Is your `log[/var/log/file.log]` item working well? Does it receive any values? Is its type set to "Zabbix agent (active)"?

Comment: Yes, is "Zabbix agent (active)". How to check if he receive any values? How can I test it?

Comment: You can see whether that item receives any values by going to "Latest data".

Comment: Yes, you are righs. There is no data for this item. Do I need to create a UserParameter for him?

Comment: No, the `log[]` item is built-in, but user parameters are a completely different topic. Make sure you have `ServerActive` in the agent configuration file. See https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/appendix/items/activepassive for more information on active items and https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/log_items on log monitoring specifically.